# React-native Redux Should business logic be inside actions or reducers

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I ve started to work on reactnative - redux project. I am totally new on this functional paradigm. My question is simple: I have different login/signup options and one of them is facebook. 
Inside my action file, i get token from facebook. I should send it to the server for checking. This request can return multiple results

- This user is new, open new user page
- This user already exist and approved, open application page
- This user already exists but hasnt approved sms verification yet, open sms verification screen.

and the question is; where should i put those logic? Should i done it all on actions or just send events to reducer and let it decide. I am confused about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on "where should my business logic live?"](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic):

> There's no single clear answer to exactly what pieces of logic should go in a reducer or an action creator. Some developers prefer to have “fat” action creators, with “thin” reducers that simply take the data in an action and blindly merge it into the corresponding state. Others try to emphasize keeping actions as small as possible, and minimize the usage of getState() in an action creator. (For purposes of this question, other async approaches such as sagas and observables fall in the "action creator" category.)
>
> This comment sums up the dichotomy nicely:
>
> > Now, the problem is what to put in the action creator and what in the reducer, the choice between fat and thin action objects. If you put all the logic in the action creator, you end up with fat action objects that basically declare the updates to the state. Reducers become pure, dumb, add-this, remove that, update these functions. They will be easy to compose. But not much of your business logic will be there. If you put more logic in the reducer, you end up with nice, thin action objects, most of your data logic in one place, but your reducers are harder to compose since you might need info from other branches. You end up with large reducers or reducers that take additional arguments from higher up in the state.

I also discussed the idea of "thick" and "thin" reducers in my blog post [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/).

Comment: Of course there is no clear answer as always, but should i choose fat actions or fat reducers? however, your blog helped me a lot especially on redux-logic which will help me to reduce size of actions and also selector functions with slice reducers. Thank you